# Php check over array?

Tags: php

I have an array containing only booleans:

```
 $l = array(0=>true,2=>false,3=>true,4=>true,5=>true);
```

I want to achieve this pseudocode:

```
If at least one element of $l is false:
    echo 'Can not do this';
else:
    echo 'Can do this';
```

Comment: Should it be _if at least one element..._?

Comment: in_array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a misspelling and the correct form is

> if at least ***one*** element in array $l is false

Then you only need to iterate over the array and fail on the first `false` value in the array.  I will not give you the answer, since it is homework and the solution is very simple.

Take a look at the [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement in the PHP manual and also the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement. That's really all you need to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
$missing_permission = array_search(false, $l);
if($missing_permission !== false) {
    echo 'No way!';
} else {
    echo 'OK!';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the [in_array](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function of php, which checks the array for a given value.

```
$l = array(0=> true, 2 => false, 3 => true, 4 => true, 5 => true);

if (in_array(FALSE, $l)) {
  echo "can not do this";
} else {
  echo "can do this";
}
```

Example: http://www.ideone.com/yv3Yf

Answer (score 1):

You might  try to use array_reduce function. Something like this:false elements.

```
   array_reduce($data, function($v, $w){ if ($w == false) { $v++; } return $v; return 1; } , 0);
```

Call back function counts number of false elements in array.
But I variant with array_search or in_array meantion before is better. Try not to use cycles of php using standard php functions which is much faster as it uses native c code.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array. If you encounter a false element, stop and print "Can not do this". If you encounter the end of the array, stop and print "Can do this".